# Mootools - getFirst().get('text') not a function?

Tags: mootools

the HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="listItem">a list item</li>
  <li id="link01">list item with ID</li>
  <li id="link02"><a href="#">another link with ID</a></li>
  <li class="lastItem"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="lastItem">the Very Last List Item</li>
</ul>
```

the JavaScript:

```
alert($$('.lastItem').getFirst('li').get('text'));
```

console returns this error:

```
TypeError: $$(...).getFirst(...).get is not a function
```

um...whut?  what did i miss?  if i take out the getFirst(), it works, but returns, of course, both `<li>` text contents... which i don't want.  just want the first...

halp.

WR!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You trying to call getFirst on Elements array($$ return elements array!) the getFirst() method is only on a dom mootools element and it will return his first child
what you are looking for is this:

```
alert($$('.lastItem')[0].get('text'));
```

Comment: this would be a great solution, but what i'm trying to target is the first <li> element, not just the first element in the array.  so this falls apart in my situation.  the first array element would actually be something else...  :P  any other ideas?  the irony is this comes right from the MooTools dox itself.  O_o

Comment: this is the first li element: `$$('.lastItem')[0]` - the function [$$](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollars) in mootools return an [Elements](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Elements) object - which has also all the array methods. what I guess you are looking for is the getFirstChild([selector]) function that works only on [Element](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element) - so in your case the search would have to be on it's parent element like this: `$('nav').getFirst('li').get('text')`

Comment: fair enough. my code doesn't really reflect what i'm looking for this to do...and that's my fault.  what it should be reading is a nested `<li>`, which you illustrated by just abstracting to `nav`.  thanks Adidi!  :D  very helpful.